# Problem typing a Select object from the MaterialUI package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to implement the MaterialUI Select component using typescript/reactjs. However, I have a problem when instantiating the Select.

I'm getting the typing error:

```
Type 'Courses' is missing the following properties from type 'Options[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2740
```

[image]

I can't understand why this error is happening, and I don't even have it, for what reason I need to include the Courses type, if what I'm passing as a parameter to the select is an object with the name "courses" and with the properties id and name. I do not understand.

**Select Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, MenuItem, TextFieldProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

interface Options {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type ITextFieldProps = TextFieldProps & {
  name: string;
  options: Options[];
};

const SelectWrapper: React.FC<ITextFieldProps> = ({
  name,
  options,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);

  const handleChange = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setFieldValue(name, value);
  };

  const configSelect = {
    ...field,
    ...otherProps,
    select: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    onChange: handleChange,
    error: false,
    helperText: '',
  };

  if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
    configSelect.error = true;
    configSelect.helperText = meta.error;
  }

  return (
    <TextField variant="outlined" {...configSelect}>
      {options.map(opt => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>
            {opt.name}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </TextField>
  );
};

export default SelectWrapper;
```

**Location where I'm calling Select:**

```
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Select
              name="course"
              label="Selecione um Curso"
              options={courses}
              size="small"
            />
          </Grid>
```

**courses object:**
I get this object from an API and pass it through the courses parameter, in the select component.

```
{ 
    {
        "id": 10053,
        "name": "Direção Defensiva – Controle de Acidentes Ambev - 2021 (Distribuição)"
    },
    {
        "id": 10052,
        "name": "Segurança na Operação de Empilhadeira – 2021"
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create Courses array?

Comment: I get the object from the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was typing incorrectly the Courses object received from the backend, I was forgetting to say that it was an object, eg Courses[].
I was typing: Courses.

Before:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  companies: Companies;
  courses: Courses;
}
```

After:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  companies: Companies;
  courses: Courses[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do
options={courses.map(({I'd, name}) => ({id, name}))}

Comment: This way I continue with the error reported in the question.